# How to limit number of objects in spring

Tags: java, multithreading, spring

I have a pojo which contains a database result set. I have almost 20 threads which run in parallel want to use this object at the same time. The system runs out of memory if I allow each thread to create a separate copy of the object. In the same time, I don't want to use Singleton as it keeps the thread waiting while another process is using the object. Is there any way I can limit the number of object 20. We are using spring protocol scope. Any help would be greatly appreciated. cheers.

Comment: Wouldn't something simple like creating object pool work?

Comment: is it possible for you to give me some sample or example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076690/java-concurrency/build-your-own-objectpool-in-java-to-boost-app-speed.html) and [this](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/examples.html) should give you a good idea of how to implement object pool, the first link is quite easy to read. Good luck and have fun :)

Comment: Thank you very much, I am looking at object pooling using spring. do you have any examples of it?